# Scientific calculator

Tags: calculus

How to calculate a polynomial using it's zero in a scientific calculator?For example If zeros are 3,5,7 then how to construct this in a scientific calculator ? Currently I m usung fx-991es calculator  but not able to get how to do that . Is there any other calculator which can do that. One more query is ther any calculator that calculate a MATRIX to power n.

Comment: Just use $(x-3)(x-5)(x-7)$

Comment: Peter please clarify how to do that i m a newbie

Comment: The TI-89 might be able to compute $A^n$ ($A$ a matrix) for small-ish $n$, depending on the size of the matrix.

For the polynomial question, you would be better off multiplying it out by hand rather than trying to memorize the symmetric expressions that give the coefficients.

Comment: If you just want to compute a value of $(x-3)(x-5)(x-7)$ for a given $x$, then do the computation (it's only using subtraction and multiplication). If you want your calculator to expand this product and return $x^3-15x^2+71x-105$ as a formula, you need a calculator that has a Computer Algebra System (CAS), such as a TI-89 or HP-50. See also Karl's answer, there are infinitely many polynomials with roots $3,5,7$, just multiply one of them by any nonzero number.

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible because more than one polynomial (even of the same degree) can have those roots.  To understand why imagine a polynomial with the desired roots. Now stretch it parallel to the  $y $ axis. The resulting polynomial is different yet has the same roots.

To illustrate: You cannot distinguish  $(x-3)(x-5)(x-7)$ from $2 (x-3)(x-5)(x-7) $ using their roots alone as they are identical, one is simply a stretched version of the other.

Answer (score 0):

The polynomial of your example is in general $P(x)=(x-3)(x-5)(x-7)Q(x)$, where $Q(x)$ is a polynomial without real zeroes (it could be simply a constant, for instance). But you must have some additional information to find $Q(x)$.

Comment: Can i construct a polynomial with it zeros

Comment: Suppose zeros of polynomial are 1,2,3 can i get the polynomial x^2-6x+11-6 from the calculator

Comment: Compute $(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$, if you just want SOME polynomial with those zeroes. The way to do that depends on the specific calculator, I suppose.

Comment: Do u know some calculator which can do that

Comment: In the sense that the resulting polynomial is shown on the display? No, sorry.

Comment: Not exactly the polynomial , if coefficient can be shown

Comment: @user3699621, There are online calculators that do what you want, for example [here](http://www.mathportal.org/calculators/polynomials-solvers/polynomials-expanding-calculator.php).